# Почему при вставке изображения на HTML-страницу оно растягивается?

Tags: css

При вставке на одну HTML страницу изображение выглядит нормально, и при вставке на другую страницу оно растягивается, хотя указаны размеры и изображение вставляется сразу после тега боди (боди стилей не имеет). В любом другом месте страницы также изображение растягивается.

Comment: Если там и правда ничего больше нет, полный код в студию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

выложите исходники страницы. 
Пользуясь телепатие предвижу что дело в padding элемента в который вставляете изображение

Comment: body
{
margin: 0 0;
padding: 0 0;
}

Катринка вставляется сразу после body

</head>
<body>

<img src="img/close.png" width="49" height="49">

Comment: дак и 2 страницу если можно.